# Extended StackPanel in universal app C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm used to windows forms but I'm trying to get the hang of the universal apps. I need an alternative to `FlowLayoutPanel` from windows forms, I'm trying to make the stack panel work in similar way but it's there's one problem - if my items reach the border of the panel they wont get to the next line they will simply move out of the visible area and appear invisible. What can i do about this  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx)